# how to print loops for odd in 1st column and even in 2nd column in wordpress

Tags: posts, wp-query

i am new to word press trying to create a time line so far i have came with this..i want the second post should be on right side in up but after running the loop its look like this please help me to achieve that.
here is my code..

```
  <div class="timeline">
    <?php $args = array(
      'category_name' => 'blog',
      'posts_per_page' => 4
    );
    $counter = get_the_ID();
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
  if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); $counter++;
    ?>
    <h4>start</h4>
  <div class="container left">
    <?php  if( $counter % 2 == 0 ):?>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
      <p><?php the_content();?></p>
    </div>
      <?php endif;?>
  </div>

  <div class="container right">
    <?php  if( $counter % 2 == !0 ):?>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
      <p><?php the_content();?></p>
    </div>
      <?php endif;?>
  </div>
  <?php  endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

[image: this is my loop output]
[image: i want this to look like this]
[image: see its printing empty div]

Comment: Could you not do this using CSS selectors for odd and even instead of adding left and right classnames?

Comment: without loop it perfectly fine but when i run the loop it display like this..

Comment: and when inspected it produce an empty div in loop

Comment: hmmm `$counter % 2 == !0` doesn't make much sense, `== !` isn't a logic operator, did you mean '!==`?

Comment: Also `li:nth-child(odd) {` `li:nth-child(even) {` there's no need to use `left` and `right` class names at all, you can get rid of all the conditional stuff and just output the left and right side the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is creating two divs for every post - a `<div class="container left">` and a `<div class="container right">`. One is empty each time, because you then check the `$counter` variable (which you've set to the post ID), and so only one of the divs ends up containing a post.

Tom's suggestion to use CSS `nth-child` is more practical. For one thing, post IDs are not always going to increment in order. If an author edits a post (with revisions on) or anytime someone uploads media or adds another post type, that post will now have the next ID, so the posts you're pulling here are very likely to be non-sequential and thus you will sometimes end up with two `"container left"` divs in a row or two `"container right"` divs in a row, because their post IDs will both be odd or even. For another, this will also solve your problem of outputting 2 divs every iteration.

Comment: mine printing the loop correctly but not at the position where i want i just added the screen short of crome inspection. it contains the empty div...and i am beginner so i don't have much knowledge of css selectors

Comment: Right. Your code specifically says to create both a "left" and a "right" container. You should read up on CSS. All you need to do is set `.timeline .container:nth-child(odd) { float:left; }` and `.timeline .container:nth-child(even) { float:right; }` (or whatever styles you're using). Take this opportunity to use your inspector to see what "left" and "right" styles are applied and just copy them into the nth-child logic.

Comment: nth child selector not working applied all the styles it displaying all on left  side

Comment: now finally its working with few adjustments...thanks a lot @WebElaine